# refresh the JPanel with values of another panel

Tags: java, swing, parameters, actionlistener, paint

I want to return values set in the first JPanel and use them to repaint the second JPanel by clicking the RYSUJ button. I need a simple solution to send the parameters:

My main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         FractalFrame gui = new FractalFrame();
         gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         gui.setVisible(true);   
    }
```

The frame:

```
   public class FractalFrame extends JFrame {

       public FractalFrame() {

         setTitle("Fractalz beta");
         setSize(800, 600);
         setResizable(false);

         FractalzGUI gui = new FractalzGUI();

         FractalJPanel panel = new FractalJPanel(gui.kol, gui.zoom, gui.radio);
         this.add(panel);
         this.add(gui, BorderLayout.EAST);

         }

     }
```

The gui class (it's first JPanel):

```
    public class FractalzGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JRadioButton mandelbrotRadio = new JRadioButton("Zbiór Mandelbrota");
private JRadioButton shipRadio = new JRadioButton("Płonący statek");
private JLabel ustawZoom = new JLabel("zoom: ");
private JTextField zoomtf = new JTextField("", 5);
private JLabel wyborKoloru = new JLabel("Wybierz kolor: ");
private String[] kolory = {"zolty", "niebieski", "czerwony", "zielony", "brazowy", "fioletowy"};
private JComboBox listaKolorow = new JComboBox(kolory);
private JButton rysuj = new JButton("Rysuj!");
public int radio=0; //1 = mandelbrot, 2 = ship
public int zoom=0;
public int kol=0;


public FractalzGUI() {

    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(mandelbrotRadio, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    this.add(shipRadio, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    this.add(ustawZoom, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    this.add(zoomtf, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    this.add(wyborKoloru, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    this.add(listaKolorow, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    this.add(rysuj, gbc);

    mandelbrotRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            shipRadio.setSelected(false);
        }
    });

    shipRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            mandelbrotRadio.setSelected(false);
        }

    });



    rysuj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (mandelbrotRadio.isSelected()) {

                radio = 1;

            } else if (shipRadio.isSelected()) {

                radio = 2;

            }

            if(zoomtf.getText().equals("")) zoom=0;
            else zoom=Integer.parseInt(zoomtf.getText());                

            switch(listaKolorow.getSelectedIndex()){
                case 0: 
                    kol = 40;
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    kol = 165;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    kol = 256;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    kol = 105;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    kol = 20;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    kol = 200;
                    break;
            }




        }


    });



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

 }
```

Comment: I don't see a second panel, and where are you stuck? where do you try to solve your problem?

Comment: you can see initializing the second JPanel (named panel) in the frame, no need to send the second panel's code, it's about the init. I want to return the three variables: kol, zoom and radio from the gui, and refresh the second panel with new values

Comment: Does my answer make sense? Do you have any questions about it?

Answer (score 2):

Forget Swing, forget GUI's. The easiest way for one object to change the state of another is for the first object to call a method of the 2nd, passing information into it. You should have one class hold an instance of the other, and then have the first one call methods on the 2nd passing information in as needed. This can all be set up in your FractalFrame constructor, by passing in an instance of one class into the other.

You can even pass both in to each other if needed, but this will tighten coupling quite a bit. 
i.e.,

```
 FractalzGUI gui = new FractalzGUI();

 FractalJPanel panel = new FractalJPanel(gui.kol, gui.zoom, gui.radio);

 // obviously these classes need setter methods
 gui.setFractalJPanel(panel);  

 this.add(panel);
 this.add(gui, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

---

**Edit**
Called out by a professional and a purist ...
Better still, use a separate non-GUI model class that holds the logic that underlies your GUI. Allow the view classes (the GUI classes) to register listeners on the model, and then when one class changes the model, all listeners are notified and can query the model as to its state, and then adjust their views accordingly.

Comment: I hope there's a model coming ;)

Comment: You got the up vote anyway ;) - started playing with Objective C and iOS, if you don't separate your models, controllers and views, they send over the goons in dark suits and shades in dark vans to have words :P